# FPDF - Class 'App\Http\Controllers\FPDF' not found

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, fpdf

For my project I have to generate a PDF file.
Stackoverflow told me to use FPDF.
So, I followed the tutorial but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public function makePdf(Request $request){
    require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF('p', 'mm', 'A4');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output();   
  }
```

This is completely following the tutorial but it doesn't work.

I tried this as well:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
```

But than again, I get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
```

to this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use FPDF;
```

because of PSR-4 autoloading namespaces you dont have to include it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the correct headers if you see this error.

Doing it something like this should help:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf');

return Response::make(PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->show('my_pdf'), 200, $headers);
```

You get the error because a pdf cannot open in a HTML page without the proper header.

Comment: I used header('Content-type: application/pdf'); And exit; But thanks my man!!